# Android Universal Image Loader: call OpenGL ES API Error

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, universal-image-loader

I'm using Universal Image Loader in my app. every things works well when i use display methods like:

```
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imagePath, imageview);
```

but when i use load methods to get a bitmap object,

```
 ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(imagePath, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
 // @Override
 public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
 // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
 }
 });
```

I got the error in logcat:

call to OpenGL ES API with no current context

so where is the problem?
**Update**:
my logcat:

```
02-21 18:39:27.232: W/ImageLoader(19090): memoryCache() and memoryCacheSize() calls overlap each other
02-21 18:39:27.242: W/ImageLoader(19090): discCache(), discCacheSize() and discCacheFileCount calls overlap each other
02-21 18:39:27.242: W/ImageLoader(19090): discCache(), discCacheSize() and discCacheFileCount calls overlap each other
02-21 18:39:38.692: E/libEGL(19090): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
02-21 18:39:38.702: D/AndroidRuntime(19090): Shutting down VM
02-21 18:39:38.702: W/dalvikvm(19090): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/1155 }} to activity {com.example.imagecaching/com.example.imagecaching.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2553)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2595)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:121)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at com.example.imagecaching.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:162)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2549)
02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090):    ... 11 more
02-21 18:39:38.752: D/dalvikvm(19090): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/graphics
/BitmapFactory$Options;.inBitmap
02-21 18:39:38.752: W/dalvikvm(19090): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 21
02-21 18:39:38.762: D/dalvikvm(19090): VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x0000
02-21 18:39:38.762: D/dalvikvm(19090): VFY: dead code 0x0002-0008 in Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/decode/ImageDecodingInfo;.copyOptions11 (Landroid/graphics/BitmapFactory$Options;Landroid/graphics/BitmapFactory$Options;)V
02-21 18:39:39.002: D/dalvikvm(19090): GC_CONCURRENT freed 238K, 48% free 2943K/5575K, external 7558K/9438K, paused 2ms+3ms
02-21 18:44:38.752: I/Process(19090): Sending signal. PID: 19090 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You are probably violating the rule that all calls to OpenGL ES and the EGL on Android must be made from a single thread (which is created by GLSurfaceView)  See: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 02-21 18:39:38.712: E/AndroidRuntime(19090): at com.example.imagecaching.MainActivity.onActivityResult mainactivity line 162

Comment: @ClayMontgomery  Thanks for your replys but my app extends activity and use xml layout for showing UI "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);".  so can you please tell me how to create an OpenGL ES thread when using XML layouts?

Comment: @gian1200 I remove the null exception and my program continue to work but the red message in log cat "call to OpenGL ES API with no current context" is still shows up. can i ignore it?

Comment: Take a look at this example in the SDK which shows how to create your own rendering thread instead of using GLSurfaceView.  It gives a lot more flexibility: android-sdk\sources\android-16\com\android\test\hwui\GLTextureViewActivity.java

Comment: i have the same problem... any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I think it is a warning and in my case it has no effect on my application running